# Flutter how to stop playing video on background state?

Tags: flutter, video-player

I'm developing app with video player using `video_player 0.10.11+1` package.

while video player is playing i put my app in background. On `AppLifecycleState.paused or AppLifecycleState.inactive` state after some time it was started playing in background.i was not getting how it started playing on background.so i have tried with  `didChangeAppLifecycleState` method on `AppLifecycleState.paused` i made video controller pause. still after that also same it was happening.

This issue was happens in Redmi & OnePlus mobiles

Case,

step 1 : while video player is playing i put my app background.

step 2 : then i opened whatsapp,facebook other apps in my phone.

step 3 : after some time video player of my app which is in background mode started playing without opening it.

```
@override
void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.paused) {
      print("Video Player AppLifecycleState Paused");
      if (_controller != null) {
       _controller.pause().then((_) {});
      }
    }
}
```

so,help me out to slove this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution? I am facing same issue now, how did you resolved it? Please help.

Comment: @AshwiniSalunkhe i tried lot but no luck. still this is issue there only happening for some devices .

Answer (score 1):

Play/pause state of videos played using [video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) is automatically handled by the plugin. Background playback is set to false by default. If [allowBackgroundPlayback](https://pub.dev/documentation/video_player_platform_interface/latest/video_player_platform_interface/VideoPlayerOptions/allowBackgroundPlayback.html) in the `VideoPlayerOptions` has been set to **true**, just make sure to set it to **false**.

Also, another possible cause of this issue is another media is being played in the background. This issue has been [resolved](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30438#issuecomment-675556558).